# How can I add tables in EF Core/database first in the package manager console?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using EF Core and was able to scaffold the initial database and table:

`Scaffold-DbContext "connection-string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables TestTable`

But I can't seem to find out how to add tables after the initial scaffold.

Comment: The tooling shipped by the EF team doesn't allow that. You need a commercial tool like LLBLGen Pro for that.

Comment: Can't you just call Scaffold-DbContext again?

Comment: @SørenLorentzen Actually, it looks like I can. It's not ideal because I have to specify every table I want, even if it's already there. And I have to change `OnConfiguring` to not hard code the connection string, as well as use the `-Force` flag to overwrite the old context. But it works. Submit the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @FransBouma That's a huge bummer. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: an Update-DbContext and dotnet ef dbcontext update to re-scaffold your DbContext, is in the pipeline, but its not prioritized yet, you can follow the progress here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831

Comment: @fedda Yes. I asked about it earlier this year on that issue: https://i.imgur.com/9H0n2Mo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command again to update the DbContext.
You could make a bat file to run the command for you. That would make it a bit easier in the long run

Comment: Just for reference for other people who may come across this question, this works, but it's a hack. It doesn't update the context. You have to `-force` it because it completely overwrites it.